# How to pass video title into a videoplayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, media

Ok, so I'm coding an app, that'll allow a user to watch promotional videos from a website.

So the URL is something like this

```
https://<url-something>/<title>/video.mp4
```

as you can see, it opens in the video player as "video.mp4". Would there be a way to change the name and send it along with the video URL?

My current code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(s));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(s), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible directly pass video title from video URL to another activity, but you could use Use [intent.putExtra(key, value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(s));
intent.putExtra("title", url); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(s), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

And get the title as below:

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

After getting title, you could display it in your view, that is an easy job.

Comment: Welp, I know that, but the problem is, that I'm trying to make it possible for everyone to play videos in their favourite media players. So that's a no then?

Comment: No, I don't think its possible. Even some third party player can receive title and display it , but we cannot know which player user like

Comment: That's correct, I'll accept your answer, as it's correct, even if it doesn't fully answer my question. Farewell